# How can the ISP block Sarawak Report even if I am entering Sarawak Report from google search?

Tags: google, censorship

[Sarawak report](http://sarawakreport.org) is blocked in Malaysia.

I  think that by doing a Google search on relevant keywords, and then click on the relevant link, I can access the website, because from what I know, the searches and clicks on Google are encrypted, and hence my ISP won't know that I am accessing **Sarawak Report**.

Apparently this is not the case; **my ISP can still block me. How does it do that?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you click on the link of a search result you simply get a redirect from google to this site, i.e. your browser is still accessing the site by its own directly and not through the servers of the search engine.

If you don't want to get this you would need to try the cached version of the site, which is sometimes offered within the search results. This cached result is then served from the search engine itself, although it might include the images on this site in a direct way again.

Answer (score 1):

Google just offers you a link to the site and not the site itself. If you click on the link its the same as you would type the link in your browser.

Your ISP  might have blocked the IP of this site. You could use a VPN or the Tor Browser to bypass that.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, the search results from google are encrypted, As soon as you click the search result the encryption breaks off and the ISP knows what site you are visiting to and blocks em.
If you just want temporary Solution **Proxy websites** are best, for long-term browsing
**Tor** is the best solution for you. Just make sure not to use TOR for personal accounts like Facebook or E-Mails other than that you can freely use ay of the restricted websites.

Goodluck

Comment: If you're using Tor only as a way to bypass access restriction, you can use HTTPS encrypted sites like or Gmail Facebook safely. If you're using Tor for anonymity though, you would want to be very careful when transmitting any identifying information about yourself over Tor, encrypted or unencrypted, as that can break your anonymity.